# Yeoman generator function in global namespace

Tags: node.js, generator, yeoman

In **yo** nodejs module, under **bin** directory, there is a file **yo**. On line 47 of that file there is this line of code:

```
var env = require("yeoman-generator")()
```

It seems that **yeoman-generator** is global function, which is called and the result is assigned to **env** variable. I don't see where and how is that function exported to a global namespace ?

Can someone help ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`require()` is how you require other Node modules. In this instance the dependency `yeoman-generator` is require()'d.

Comment: Yes I know what is required, but from where ? I don't see yeoman-generator module exported in a global environment.

Comment: You can't require global modules in Node. It's a local dependency: https://github.com/yeoman/yo/blob/master/package.json#L30

Comment: Sorry, it is local 
Problem was that I was expecting to see "yeoman-generator" exported explicitly from a file. Instead, createEnv function is  returned from main.js file and attached to "yeoman-generator" namespace ( which is the name of the node_module and a directory )